# How to Test a BAD fingerprint in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

Doing research for my team. I see how to add a fingerprint in Android Emulator and sent a good event.

```
adb -e emu finger touch <finger_id>
```

What if I want to test a BAD fingerprint?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

While ADB is useful for a lot of things, I use the Fingerprint menu in the emulator's extended controls instead. Here's how I've been able to test it:

1. Open the Settings app -> Security -> Fingerprint
2. If you have any existing fingerprints, delete them
3. Tap Add fingerprint. At this point you will be asked to touch the sensor.
4. Tap the three dots (...) for the Extended controls and select the Fingerprint menu.
5. Tap Touch The Sensor multiple times to register "Finger 1".
6. Repeat the previous step with Finger 2, 3, etc. depending on how many "correct" fingerprints you want to add.

When a fingerprint scan dialog is shown in an app, select a finger from the extended controls and click "Touch the Sensor". I've tested this with Google's [FingerprintDialog](https://developer.android.com/samples/FingerprintDialog/index.html) sample code. If you only added Finger 1, attempting to use Finger 2 would report that it wasn't a match.

Comment: works well cool

Answer (score 2):

You just need to touch with a finger id which was never registered in the emulators security setting.

Comment: Yes, there is a drop-down list with a lot of finger ids